# contact us page title and meta description changes not reflating in magento2

Tags: magento2, contact-us, meta-title, meta-description

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Contact us </title>
        <meta name="description" content="Drop Down Your Query for the Promt Replies at info@abc.in and for Customer Care Support we have a Contact Number, Contact Us at  0000000000. Chat Support also Available. Track Orders." />
        <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run the below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* var/page_cache/* -rf var/cache/*
chmod -R 777 Root path/*
```

If you change your code in XML you need to run setup:upgrade

**Try this**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
    <head>
        <title>Contact Us</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="content">
           //Your Block
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I run these commands but only description changed title not changed

Comment: Its showing me customer login title in title tag

Comment: I updated my answer please try it, i had used this code it is working

Comment: @jykmhar123 Weather the code is working

Comment: Thanks its working @sabareesh ji

Answer (score 0):

@sabareesh How to translate Meta Description ? `<meta name="description" content="Enquiry?">`